# how to remove br without breakage of formating text?

Tags: jquery

How can I remove the **br** tag without breaking the formatting in jquery .I am able to remove **br** but it breaks my formatting. I tried such approach:

$("#realTimeContents br").remove();

```
    <div id="realTimeContents" > dfgdfgdf
                             <br>
    <br>                      
                                 bdfsfdsg

                                     <br>
                                     ipiopixdgfdfh

                                           <br>
                                     ipiopixdgfdfh
</div>
```

After removing it look like this:

**dfgdfgdf bdfsfdsg ipiopixdgfdfh ipiopixdgfdfh**

Expected result:

```
dfgdfgdf


                                     bdfsfdsg


                                         ipiopixdgfdfh


                                         ipiopixdgfdfh
```

Comment: any other solution because I an getting data from server with br tag I to formate my test

Comment: What you're trying to do is really unclear. Are you presenting it somewhere? How do you see all those spaces when in HTML you can't see them?

Comment: yes I Am representing on my device .

Comment: I am using search functionality .I am getting data from server with formating with some br like that but when I search b character then it show br tag http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/xg2Kp/

Comment: So I remove br tag before search but it remove formatting

Answer (score 1):

I would add a style white-space:pre on the container. That will preserve the whitespace formating.

```
<div id="realTimeContents" style="white-space:pre" >
```

This is the same as using a `pre` tag, but it lets you keep the original structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably suround your text in pre-tags to try to keep the formatting... 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Comment: @DipeshParmar: W3Fools doesn't have any content anymore. Just link to the MDN or something.

Comment: I am not able to use pre

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `<pre>` tag...

even `stackoverflow` doing it....

i think you might realize it while adding question into stackoverflow because you are adding that format into question for showing us result that you want.